# Related content - does not display current node

Tags: drupal-7

I am currently working on displaying related articles for my content type (article). I created view block for that specific content type, but when i for example display node with id 191 on the sidebar where my related articles are placed, its showing the title of node id 191 too.

block view settings:
aggregation: Yes
Fields: tried to add content nid, but nothing showed

What's wrong with my settings, and what should I modify? One more question its possible to show these related items randomly?

Comment: you want to prevent displaying current node from sidebar items right? 
other nodes from article type except current node?

Comment: @Ali_Hr Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

1. in field section add this field: "Content: Nid"
2. then check "Exclude from display" to prevent displaying this field
3. in FILTER CRITERIA , add a php filter
4. in Filter code section add the following code:

> ```
> $nid = arg(1);
>
> if($row->nid == $nid){
>
>    return true;
>
> }
> ```

you are good to go.